# Spring-boot default filter registration does not allow ERROR dispatcher

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

We are using spring-security in our spring-boot-mvc application, (1.3.0.RELEASE ) and looks like ERROR requests are not been properly handled by the default spring security filter chain.

Looks like **org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AbstractFilterRegistrationBean** only registers filters for

`static final EnumSet NON_ASYNC_DISPATCHER_TYPES = 
EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.INCLUDE,DispatcherType.REQUEST);`

but is not allowing DispatcherType.ERROR as non-async type.

Does anyone know how can it be overriden ?

Thanks.

Comment: I see that you've posted a question to the Spring Boot tracker and received the answer: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4696 So, you could copy&paste it here and accept your own answer later.